# How to identify a column with name exist in all tables?

Tags: mysql

i want to query a database which has huge tables for the columns with specific name

ex: fetch all the tables which has column name like 'name'

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to query the table metadata from the system tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT table_name -- you might want to add DISTINCT if you use pattern matching with LIKE
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_schema = SCHEMA()
   AND column_name = 'name' -- or column_name LIKE '%name%'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60f69/1)** demo

Comment: > Thanks it worked...Also the below also works fine.                  > SELECT table_name,column_name FROM information_schema.columns
>WHERE column_name LIKE '%tax%'

Comment: also, How to search stored procedures containing a particular text?  > select routine_name, routine_definition
      from information_schema.routines
      where routine_definition like '%tax_id%'
      and routine_type='procedure'

Comment: @user2323036 You're quite welcome :) Yes you can search for stored procedures this way